# How can I display a logo and its description in the same line using iTextSharp?

Tags: c++-cli, itext

I want to show a logo and its description in a  pdf using itextSharp.

Example:
Logo      LogoDescription

My below code shows logo and its description on two different lines

```
Document^ doc = gcnew Document(iTextSharp::text::PageSize::LETTER,10,10,42,32);
doc->Open();

// add image
iTextSharp::text::Image^ bmp = iTextSharp::text::Image::GetInstance("bts_logo.bmp");
bmp->ScaleToFit(50,100);
bmp->Border = iTextSharp::text::Rectangle::BOX;
bmp->BorderColor = iTextSharp::text::BaseColor::RED;
bmp->BorderWidth = 2;

doc->Add(bmp);
doc->Add(gcnew Phrase("Logo description", gcnew iTextSharp::text::Font(iTextSharp::text::Font::FontFamily::HELVETICA, 11, iTextSharp::text::Font::BOLD)));
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a `Phrase` (e.g. a description) next to an `Image` (e.g. a picture), you typically create a `PdfPTable`:

```
PdfPTable table^ = gcnew PdfpTable(2);
```

This will create a table that shows borders by default. You can change this by adding this line:

```
table->DefaultCell->Border = iTextSharp::text::Rectangle::NO_BORDER;
```

You then add the image and the text as cells:

```
table->AddCell(bmp);
table->AddCell(phrase);
```

Where `bmp` is an instance of the `Image` class, and `phrase` is an instance of the `Phrase` class.

You then add the table to the document:

```
doc->Add(table);
```

The table will have borders by default, but as I am not familiar with the programming language you are using, you probably know better how to change the border of the default cell to `NO_BORDER` than I do.

Comment: Thanks for the idea ,below code helped me to remove border from the table 
              table->DefaultCell->Border = iTextSharp::text::Rectangle::NO_BORDER;

Comment: OK, thank you for giving me the right syntax. I have updated my answer for further reference. Please mark the answer as accepted so that I can refer to it in the future.